# Quickest way to do PHP array_filter on very big array or load less data from a file?

Tags: php, arrays, file, array-filter

### Problem

I have a txt file that is almost 2 Mb.
It has lines with a time, date, name and a message.
I would like to do a regular expression on each line, so I start by reading the file into an array.

```
$array1 = file('<file_name>');
```

**Between each line in the file is a whiteline that I would like to skip.**
On stackoverflow I found the following peace of code witch seems to be ok.

```
array_values( array_filter($array1, 'trim'));
```

**My problem is that this takes very long to proces.**

### Questions

1. Is there a way to skip the whitelines while reading the file, before I make the array, so the array that I start with has way less keys?
2. If I have to use the array_filter function. Wich way is faster and best for memory use?

---

```
$array2 = array_values( array_filter($array1));
```

or

```
$array2 = array_values( array_filter($array1));
unset($array1);
```

Comment: Look at the available flags from `file()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! Can't believe I missed that. Would still be nice to get an answer on the second question though...

Comment: First one is faster, because you don't unset the first array. With the second one you then end up with more memory, since you unset the first array, which you don't user anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optimize memory, you'll have to read each line and process it.

1. Open file
2. Start loop
3. read line
4. process line
5. save data processed
6. End loop

Use fopen, fread, fclose php functions. You'll find some information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)

Comment: I guess you mean I should use fopen() instead, right?

Comment: @MarcvanNieuwenhuijzen: Yes, everytime you want to open a fairly large file, you want better control over your file operations than just dumping the file into an array. 
Also, you can use `fgets()` instead of `fread()` to read a line instead of a set amount of characters.